# Translating poisson equation to sfepy code

Tags: finite-element, python, differential-equations

As the title suggests, I am trying to convert the Poisson equation:

[image]

Into sfepy code that can solve the differential euqation problem numerically.

I am trying to modify the tutorial on lienar elasticity which is similar but I am just causing it to crash.

Comment: What is sfepy? Is this a software package?

Comment: It's a python FEM software package. I mentioned SFepy but any python FEM solver would work really.